# How do I handle blank array elements in a loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a Ruby script that iterates through a list of projects.  For each project, it iterates through an HTML table, collecting each row's `td` text and adding it to an array.

The problem is, when the table is blank for that particular project, it adds an empty array to my 2-d array, which is then causing an error when I try to use that array to insert the data into a SQL database. How can I prevent the empty array from being appended to the beginning of my array?

```
projects.each do |project_id|
  url = "http://myurl.com/InventoryMaster.aspx?Qtr=%s&Client=%s" % [qtr,project_id[1]]

  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  table = page.at('my_table')

  rows = Array.new
  table.search('tr').each do |tr|
    cells = Array.new

    tr.search('td').each do |cell|
      cells.push(cell.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip)
    end 
    # add the project id to the cells array, and get ride of other array elements I don't need.
    cells.insert(1, project_id[0])
    cells.slice!(11, 6)
    cells.delete_at(8)
    cells.delete_at(2)
    cells.delete_at(0)
    rows.push(cells)
  end

  # first row in the array in the html table is headers.  get rid of those.
  rows.shift
  # last row in the html table is the footers.  get rid of those too.
  rows.pop

  p rows

end
```

Here's the HTML I'm parsing, as requested:

```
<table id="ctl00_MainContent_gvSearchResults" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" 
border="1" style="color:Black;background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;border-color:Tan;
border-width:1px;border-style:solid;" rules="cols">

<caption></caption>
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:Tan;font-weight:bold;">
#I don't need the headers.
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family:arial,tahoma;font-size:Smaller;">
        <td>not needed</td>
        <td>not needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>
        <td align="right">needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>
        <td>not needed</td>
        <td>needed</td>

#I don't need any of the remaining td's in this row either.
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
#this row is the footer, and it isn't needed either.
    <tr style="background-color:Tan;">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Once I've parsed the table, I need to add in the project id, which is part of a key value pair contained in the `projects` array.

Comment: Show some sample HTML to make your question complete. With that we can easily show you how to parse correctly, instead of trying to mop up afterwards.

Comment: stick `next if table.children.size <= 1` (something to check that my_table is blank) after `table = page.at('my_table')` this should skip blank tables

Comment: @Tthe Tin Man - I added my html table.  I should mention that the last 3 td's that I need to parse are dates, and need to be parsed as mm-dd-yyyy.  I just realized that I also have a problem with this script when the day portion of the date is a single digit.

Comment: @Bjhaid - this solution didn't work for me.  I was able to solve the issue by first getting a count of the rows in the table, and placing that in a conditional:  if rowCount > 0 ...then loop through and gather the cells, otherwise, move on to the next project.

Answer (score 2):

Try filtering the `projects` array before iterating:

```
projects.reject(&:empty?).each do |project_id|
```

Now you will be iterating over non empty arrays only.

Example time:

```
array = [ [1], [], [2, 3] ]
array.reject &:empty? # => [ [1], [2, 3] ]
```

Neat.

Comment: this returns: `empty?': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: fyi, the projects array is filled with key => value pairs.  Not sure if that has anything to do with the error I'm getting from your solution.

Comment: The array is filled with hashes or projects is a hash?. The former would work

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [`delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) method:

```
array = [ [1], [], [2, 3] ]
array.size # => 3
array.delete_if &:empty? # => [ [1], [2, 3] ]    
array.size # => 2
```